# Progress bar won't hide when I want it too? VB

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar, picturebox, visible, invisible

Hi I am creating a simple game in VB where monsters randomly spawn in and disappear when you click on the picture box several times. Each enemy has a progress bar on top which should disappear when the enemy dies (when the enemies disappear).

The code I am trying is as follows:

```
    Private Sub Form1...
    progbarstart()
    progbarshow()
    End sub

    Private Sub progbarstart()
    ProgBarEnemy.Visible = false
    End sub

    Private Sub progbarshow()
    If PicBoxEnemy.Visible = true then
    ProgBarEnemy.Visible = true
    Else
    ProgBarEnemy.Visible = false
    End If
    End sub()
```

I think this all the info you will need there is more code which I think is irrelevant. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry I may not have been clear. The progress bar will be invisible to start with. When the enemy spawns I want its coressponding progress bar to spawn with it. And then when the enemy dies I want the progress bar to then disappear. This is then repeated over and over again until the user dies.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Look for the VisibleChanged event and put this code in. it will update your progressbar when the picture box is visible or not

```
 Private Sub PicBoxEnemy_VisibleChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PicBoxEnemy.VisibleChanged
        progbarshow()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Good catch! Something I hadn't considered when I read the question!

Comment: Finally... this got it to work! Thank you so much I needed this to work to progress further into my coursework and now I can.